# Event Hub - Key Vault

Tags: azure, security, azure-keyvault, azure-eventhub

Is it common practice to store the EH Connection string, clientid and secret in Key Vault?

Do you then refer the producer client to retrieve from Key Vault stored

MSFT documentation is a bit more focused on web apps to me.

My noddy interpretation

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing your secrets like connection strings in something like KeyVault is generally always a good idea.

For your particular scenario this seems valid as well. Even better would be, though, if you could use [Azure AD authentication directly against the Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory). This depends on whether the client SDK you use does support it yet.

Comment: Using MSAL (Microsoft Security Auth Library) is in my thinking at the moment. I would still need to issue Client ID/Secret though wouldn't I with AD Auth as a one time operation?

Comment: What do you mean by MSAL?

Comment: yes, @Deason your app would still need to authenticate against AAD (using client ID/secret, managed identity (when running in Azure), etc). However, once you have that, you don't need to go the extra step via KeyVault but could directly authenticate against EventHub

Comment: So... Key Vault as a source for third parties to retrieve my EH Connection String, Client ID and Secret....then with the details they'll use AAD.